# pdfshuffler not avaliable on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: software-installation, 22.04

After an install of 22.04, I am attempting to install `pdfshuffler` but it appears to not be available.

I'm running this command to install it:

```
sudo apt-get install pdfshuffler
```

and the result is:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package pdfshuffler
```

Will this be available in the future or did I try to install incorrectly?

Comment: It is indeed not availble in the 20.04 repositories. The last release on their SorceForge page is from 2012. Whoever maintained it all these years probably gave up.

Answer (score 10):

Packages may be removed from the Ubuntu repositories if they are not updated, and rely on outdated libraries that are not anymore shipped with Ubuntu. That may be the case with Pdf-Shuffler.

Instead consider [PDF Arranger](https://github.com/pdfarranger/pdfarranger). This is functionally equivalent (it actually is a fork of PDF-Shuffler) and is better maintained.

Comment: Many thanks.  I'll give that a try.

Answer (score 2):

You can install PDF Arranger on Ubuntu 22.04 - it has the same functionality and a similar interface to PDF Shuffler.

Install PDF Arranger on Ubuntu:

1. Launch a Terminal window with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>.
2. Install the latest Pike PDF:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip python3-distutils-extra python3-wheel python3-gi python3-gi-cairo gir1.2-gtk-3.0 gir1.2-poppler-0.18 gir1.2-handy-1 python3-setuptools
```

3. Install PDF Arranger:

```
pip3 install --user --upgrade https://github.com/pdfarranger/pdfarranger/zipball/main
```

Comment: It is also in the Ubuntu Software app store for me on 22.10